# Wordpress theme custom css does not work when screen resize

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I modify the site and problem is 3 fold:

1. I want to make border around product and product price. So I tried to use pseudo element under the original element. This gives almost expected result for Chrome and Mozilla:

   @media all{

   ```
   ul#products-grid.products.products-grid li.animate a{position: relative !important;
   }


   ul#products-grid.products.products-grid li.animate a:hover:before{
           content: '';
           position: absolute;
           top: -15px;
           left: -15px;
           right: -15px;
           bottom: -25px;
           background: red;
           border: 5px solid #E2E2E2 !important;
           z-index: -1;
       }
   }
   ```

However when I resize in chrome and mozilla and WHEN I reduce the screen size such that 3 product can not stay in same row then, css DOES NOT work.

2. It does not work in IE in no way, in any screen size.
3. It does not work even when I refresh at small screen size. Any alternative and full working solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your theme has media queries and then the css is overwritten when you resize! the solution is to put the css into the media queries

Comment: where you change the css?

Comment: They put a custom css field in theme options but I could not find in which file these css are included dynamicaly. I found that they replace custom JS codes in header.php file but could not find where they replace custom css files. But not in style.css. If you offer a place I can try.